# Neukirch's motivation for $p$-adic numbers

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, p-adic-number-theory

I've started reading Neukirch's Algebraic Number Theory book and at the beginning of Chapter II he starts his motivation for the $p$-adic numbers as follows:

*"The idea originated from the observation made in the last chapter that the numbers $f\in\mathbb{Z}$ may be viewed in analogy with the polynomials $f(z)\in\mathbb{C}[z]$ as functions on the space $X$ of prime numbers in $\mathbb{Z}$, associating to them their "value" at the point $p\in X$, i.e., the element*

$\begin{equation}
f(p):=f \mod p
\end{equation}$

*in the residue class field $\kappa(p)=\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$.
This point of view suggests the further question: whether not only the "value" of the integer $f\in\mathbb{Z}$ at $p$, but also the higher derivatives of $f$ can be reasonably defined."*

My question is: **If we define the higher derivatives of $f\in\mathbb{Z}$ at $p$ as the coefficientes of its $p$-adic expansion (as he does later on), can we give these derivatives an interpretation somehow analogous to the analytical one that goes with the $f(z)\in\mathbb{C}[z]$ polynomials?**

I'm asking this because if there is no interpretation other than "coefficientes of the expansion", it seems like a very artificial analogy to me. I mean, if not, why would he even mention derivatives instead of just saying something like: "we expand functions this way, we expand integers this way and it's kind of similar."

Any explanations and/or motivations are welcome.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think his point is that if one takes $X=\mathbb{A}^1_\mathbb{C}$ as a variety with sheaf $\mathcal{O}_X$, then for any point $p\in X$ one has that $\widehat{\mathcal{O}_{X,p}}=\mathbb{C}[[z-p]]$ and the map $\mathbb{C}[z]=\mathcal{O}_{X,x}\to \widehat{\mathcal{O}_{X,p}}$ is just taking $f\in\mathbb{C}[z]$ and expanding it as a Taylor series at $p$. Similarly, one may view the $p$-adic case as taking the scheme $X=\mathbb{Z}$, some global section $f\in\mathbb{Z}=\mathcal{O}_X(X)$ and mapping it to $\widehat{\mathcal{O}_{X,p}}=\mathbb{Z}_p$. So, yes, in some sense, it is like taking higher

Comment: derivatives. One can see this if you think of $\widehat{\mathcal{O}_{X,p}}$ as $\varprojlim \mathcal{O}_{X,p}/\mathfrak{m}_p^n$. Mapping $f$ in $\mathcal{O}_X(X)$ to $\mathcal{O}_{X,p}/\mathfrak{m}_p$ is like taking the constant term, the ring $\mathcal{O}_{X,p}/\mathfrak{m}_p^2$ is like taking the linear term, etc. So, the inverse limit is like taking the Taylor expansion.

Comment: Beyond Alex's comments, the analogy between numbers and functions is everywhere in number theory, as it's extremely common to find the same problems phrased in the language of both number fields and function fields.  In many cases, it's easier to prove theorems in the function field case, and this motivates work in the more "classical" arithmetic case.

Comment: @BobbyGrizzard In fact, as I recall, the analogy with complex functions was Hensel's original motivation in defining $p$-adic numbers.

Comment: @Kimball I think that the analogy is quite well (at least for an undergraduate) explained in first chapter (called Aperitif, as far as I remember) of Gouvea's book.

Comment: What disturbs me most about trying to give meaning to a particular ”coefficient” in a $p$-adic expansion is that these coefficients depend so strongly on your choice of representatives in $\Bbb Z$ or $\Bbb Z_p$ for the elements of $\Bbb F_p$, the residue field. For $\Bbb Z_5$, for instance, maybe you want to use $\{-2,-1,0,1,2\}$ for your possible “coefficients” of your expansion. Makes perfectly good sense. Unless you want to go all the way into abstraction and represent a $p$-adic integer by a Witt vector, it seems to me that the analogy with power series is extremely weak.

Comment: @Lubin I disagree in some sense. I think the analogy I mentioned above is pretty concrete. There is also this issue with regards to power series (albeit easier to fix). Abstractly $\widehat{\mathcal{O}_{X,x}}$ is a power series ring, and choosing an explicit isomorphism is choosing a center for the power series expansion. So, there are no unique coefficients, but 'natural ones', similarly to the case of p-adics.

Comment: Well, one can argue forever on this, but I maintain that the only “natural” coefficients for $\Bbb Z_p$ are the Teichmüller representatives, which (except for $2$ and $3$) aren’t in $\Bbb Z$.

Comment: Thanks guys! I didn't really understand much of what Alex said on his first comment beucase (forgot to mention) I'm still an 2-year undergrad and don't really understand varieties and sheaves yet, but I'll try to look it up on the internet. This question was more like a curiosity to me. I'll just keep reading and in the future hopefully I can read this post again and fully understand it. Thanks again to all of you.

Answer (score 0):

"My question is: If we define the higher derivatives of f∈Z at p as the coefficientes of its p-adic expansion (as he does later on), can we give these derivatives an interpretation somehow analogous to the analytical one that goes with the f(z)∈C[z] polynomials?"

Answer: At the following link

https://mathoverflow.net/questions/55244/why-must-nilpotent-elements-be-allowed-in-modern-algebraic-geometry/378811#378811

you will find an elementary construction of a "Taylor morphism"

T1. $T^l: E \rightarrow J^l(E)$

for any commutative ring $A$ and any left $A$-module $E$. If $A:=k[x_1,..,x_n]$
with $k$ a field of characteristic zero, you get a map

T2. $T^l: A \rightarrow J^l(A):=A\otimes_k A/I^{l+1}$

defined by $T^l(f(x_1,..,x_n)):=f(y_1,..,y_n)$. Let $dx_i:=y_i-x_i$. You may prove that there is an isomorphism

T3. $J^l(A)\cong A\{dx_1^{l_1}\cdots dx_n^{l_n}: \sum_i l_i\leq l\}$.

Hence the left $A$-module $J^l(A)$ is a free $A$-module on the set $\{dx_1^{l_1}\cdots dx_n^{l_n}: \sum_i l_i\leq l\}$. In this situation it follows the
element $T^l(f(x_1,..,x_n))$ is the Taylor expansion of the polynomial $f$ in the variables $x_i$.

Comment: "I think his point is that if one takes X=A1C as a variety with sheaf OX, then for any point p∈X one has that OX,pˆ=C[[z−p]] and the map C[z]=OX,x→OX,pˆ is just taking f∈C[z] and expanding it as a Taylor series at p. Similarly, one may view the p-adic case as taking the scheme X=Z, some global section f∈Z=OX(X) and mapping it to OX,pˆ=Zp."

Answer: The fiber of the $A$-module $J^l(A)$ at a $k$-rational point $\mathfrak{m}$ is the local ring $A/\mathfrak{m}^{l+1}$, hence this construction may be related to the construction mentioned in the comments above.

In Neukirch, Prop 2.6 page 114 the following isomorphism is constructed:

There is for every non-zero prime $p$ a canonical isomorphism

$T_p: \mathbb{Z}_{p}\cong \mathbb{Z}[[x]]/(x-p)$
and a canonical injective map $i_p: \mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}_p$.

There is a canonical map $T: \mathbb{Z}\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}[[x]]$ and we recover the map $i_p$ by passing to the quotient $P(p): \mathbb{Z}[[x]] \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}[[x]]/(x-p)$.

$i_p:=P(p)\circ T: \mathbb{Z}\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}[[x]]/(x-p)\cong \mathbb{Z}_p$.

Hence all the injections $i_p$ can be constructed from one "global" map $T$.
We may pass to "spectra" $C:=Spec(\mathbb{Z}[[x]])$ and $S:=Spec(\mathbb{Z})$
and the canonical map

$\pi: C \rightarrow S$.

The ideal $I(p):=(x-p) \subseteq \mathbb{Z}[[x]]$ corresponds to a closed subscheme $C_p:=Z(x-p)\subseteq C$ and we get a canonical morphism $\pi_p: C_p\rightarrow S$. There is a corresponding map of structure sheaves

$\pi_p^{\#}: \mathcal{O}_S \rightarrow (\pi_p)_*\mathcal{O}_{C_p}$

whose global sections is the canonical map $i_p:\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}_p$. Hence all maps $i_p$ may be given a "geometric" construction using the map $\pi$: You restrict the map $\pi$ to the closed subscheme $C_p$ and pass to global sections.